# creating a loop to insert data into postgres database

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, rest

I'm creating a REST API to insert data into Postgres database(without any framework i.e, core python) I am able to save one set of data how to save multiple set of data in to database.

I have created one list " record_to_insert = (5, 'One Plus 63', 9500) " its getting inserted successfully but multiple set of data an unable to insert.  I have seen number of tutorials available for web service but they are using Django,Flask etc. framework

```
import psycopg2
import json
with open("db.json") as data_file: //file or data i would like to receive from Clint like postman
    record_to_insert = json.load(data_file)
record_to_insert = [{"id": 5, "MODEL": "test", "PRICE": 500}, {"id": 15, "MODEL": "testgdh", "PRICE": 5000}] //extract data as json data
//record_to_insert = (5, 'One Plus 63', 9500) //this list is inserting into DB
   connection = psycopg2.connect(// Connection String)
   cursor = connection.cursor()`//for connection`enter code here`
   postgres_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO mobile (id, model, price) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"""
   cursor.execute(postgres_insert_query, record_to_insert)
   connection.commit()
```

How to insert multiple json dataset in postgres databa`<code>`se using REST API please guide me where I'm doing wrong I'm new in Python

Comment: use batch insert techniques

Comment: Could you provide some link for referance

Answer (score 0):

```
import psycopg2
import json
with open("db.json") as data_file:
    records = json.load(data_file)

records_obj = StringIO.StringIO()
records_obj.write('\n'.join(records))
records_obj.seek(0)

connection = psycopg2.connect(// Connection String)
cursor = connection.cursor()`//for connection`enter code here`
cursor.copy_from(records_obj, "mobile")
```

This would work if the json data structure is same as that of your table schema

Comment: my table structue is this only /* id bigint,
  model character varying,
  price bigint */ so i sud not store json data inside db

Comment: Can you explain that code, the function definition of `copy_from`? What is "mobile"?

Comment: mobile is table name; I would say In short i have three field in `mobile` table with `id bigint, model character varying, price bigint  `  i want to store multiple set of  json data using postman into `mobile` table

Comment: Abhinaw, you need to iterate over the refords list and select the fields which you require and build another list and pass that